# Question about an inequality for Levy Processes

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, markov-process, levy-processes

Let $(X_t)_t$ be a standard Levy process. We assume $t\mapsto X_t$ is continuous in probability or a.s. cadlag.

In this case, why does the continuity of $x\mapsto e^{i\xi \cdot x}$ implies that there is for every $\epsilon >0$ some $\delta>0 $ such that
$$E|e^{i\xi\cdot (X_t - X_s)}-1|\le \epsilon + 2P(|X_t - X_s|\ge \delta)?$$

I think I have to use that $e^{i\xi\cdot x}$ is $1$ if $x $ is near zero but I've been thinking about a way to understand  this but could not come up with a clear solution.
I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: What are $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?

Comment: @Ilya Sorry I neglected that statement.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $$E|e^{i\xi\cdot (X_t - X_s)}-1|\le \epsilon + 2P(|X_t - X_s|\ge \delta.$$ (for fixed $\xi$. In fact we can make this uniform for $\xi$ bounded).

To see that write $$E|e^{i\xi\cdot (X_t - X_s)}-1|=E|e^{i\xi\cdot (X_t - X_s)}-1|1_{|X_t-X_s| \leq \delta}+E|e^{i\xi\cdot (X_t - X_s)}-1|1_{|X_t-X_s|> \delta}.$$ In the first term use continuity of the exponential function at $0$ and in the second term use the fact that $|e^{i\xi\cdot (X_t - X_s)}-1|\leq 2$